# Content-Security-Policy : allow frame-ancestors domain not working

Tags: php, content-security-policy

i'd like to embed an OpenStreetMap iframe in my PHP webpage ; but i have this kind of error in any web browser :

```
Content Security Policy: « x-frame-options » ignored due to the directive « frame-ancestors ».
```

yet I did add this code :

```
header( 'Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors openstreetmap.org' ) ;
```

I'v also look here (but it didn't help) :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

https://openweb.eu.org/articles/content-security-policy (in French)

What' wrong ?
Thanx

Comment: The error message simply tells you that specifying `frame-ancestors` takes priority over `x-frame-options`, when both are set. But you can not add this from your end - OSM is the one that must allow for their content to be shown in your iframe. If that doesn’t work, then maybe you did not choose the correct resource to embed to begin with?

Comment: Yep, thanx a lot !

Answer (score 0):

The soluce is to embed the right url !

This one is wrong :

```
https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=11/48.8589/2.3469
```

But this one is ok :

```
https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=2.115554809570313%2C48.746228791937774%2C2.578353881835938%2C48.97165373099147
```

That's it !